# Failed to launch pgAdmin4. Error: Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, pgadmin-4

### pgAdmin Runtime Environment

Python Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3"
Runtime Config File: "/home/julien/.config/pgadmin/runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py"
Webapp Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 -s /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
Environment:

- GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS: JS ERROR;JS LOG
- LC_TIME: fr_FR.UTF-8
- USER: julien
- XDG_SESSION_TYPE: wayland
- SHLVL: 0
- HOME: /home/julien
- OLDPWD: /home/julien
- DESKTOP_SESSION: ubuntu
- GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE: /usr/share/applications/pgadmin4.desktop
- GTK_MODULES: gail:atk-bridge
- GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE: ubuntu
- LC_MONETARY: fr_FR.UTF-8
- MANAGERPID: 2723
- DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
- GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID: 409396
- WAYLAND_DISPLAY: wayland-0
- LOGNAME: julien
- _: /usr/bin/gnome-session
- rvm_bin_path: /usr/share/rvm/bin
- JOURNAL_STREAM: 8:37688
- XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
- USERNAME: julien
- GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID: this-is-deprecated
- PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin
- SESSION_MANAGER: local/sunchain:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2935,unix/sunchain:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2935
- INVOCATION_ID: b0a4bd7f387b4b94b2d1ad6290b4faa6
- LC_ADDRESS: fr_FR.UTF-8
- XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /run/user/1000
- XDG_MENU_PREFIX: gnome-
- GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY: :1
- DISPLAY: :0
- LANG: en_US.UTF-8
- LC_TELEPHONE: fr_FR.UTF-8
- XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: ubuntu:GNOME
- XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP: ubuntu
- XMODIFIERS: @im=ibus
- XAUTHORITY: /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.OGNI80
- SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER: gnome-keyring
- SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
- LC_NAME: fr_FR.UTF-8
- SHELL: /usr/bin/zsh
- QT_ACCESSIBILITY: 1
- GDMSESSION: ubuntu
- rvm_prefix: /usr/share
- LC_MEASUREMENT: fr_FR.UTF-8
- LC_IDENTIFICATION: fr_FR.UTF-8
- rvm_version: 1.29.12 (manual)
- GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT: stderr
- QT_IM_MODULE: ibus
- PWD: /home/julien
- XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
- LC_NUMERIC: fr_FR.UTF-8
- LC_PAPER: fr_FR.UTF-8
- rvm_path: /usr/share/rvm
- GDK_BACKEND: x11
- NO_AT_BRIDGE: 1
- PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 34035
- PGADMIN_INT_KEY: dbb4e565-1e23-474d-bd74-c3d8606022cc
- PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF

---

Failed to launch pgAdmin4. Error:
Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT

Comment: what is the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have handle the error to downgrade pyhton3.10 to python3.9 and error fixed.

Just track the steps:

1. Install python3.9
2. Switch 3.10 to 3.9

You can use the link to do these steps.

https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-python-3-9-or-3-8-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish/

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when I updated the packages after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Save your time and simply reinstall pgAdmin 4

[Link to official doc and follow the simple steps](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/) (mentioned at the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

for Kali GNU/Linux Rolling users, just follow the procedure on the pgAdmin4 page, or click on this link to take you there https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/, and if you reach the second command just change the `$(lsb_release -cs)` to `bookworm` and continue with the rest but make sure to uninstall the previously installed pgAdmin4 by running this command `sudo apt remove pgadmin4-server`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I updated Ubuntu 20 to 22 and the Postgres stopped working with the above-mentioned error.

So downgrading from Python 3.10 to 3.9 or 3.8 worked.

follow the steps here, https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-python-3-9-or-3-8-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading python from 3.10 to 3.8 works. Here's a [guide](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-python-3-9-or-3-8-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish/) on how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

On **Kali 2023.4** and did the procedures to install **pgadmin4** described at the following link https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

The installation procedure was:

```
curl -fsS https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/packages-pgadmin-org.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb \[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/packages-pgadmin-org.gpg\] https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" \> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop
```

But, when I tried to launch pgadmin4 from menu bar, the GUI just kept loading for a long time and then ended up showing the error bellow:

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3"
Runtime Config File: "/home/cd/.config/pgadmin/runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py"
Webapp Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 -s /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - POWERSHELL_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: 1
  - USER: cd
  - XDG_SEAT: seat0
  - XDG_SESSION_TYPE: x11
  - DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: 1
  - SSH_AGENT_PID: 1272
  - HOME: /home/cd
  - DESKTOP_SESSION: lightdm-xsession
  - XDG_SEAT_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
  - GTK_MODULES: gail:atk-bridge
  - DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
  - COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT: 1
  - QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME: qt5ct
  - LOGNAME: cd
  - QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR: 0
  - XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
  - XDG_SESSION_ID: 2
  - PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
  - _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
  - XDG_SESSION_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
  - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /run/user/1000
  - XDG_MENU_PREFIX: xfce-
  - LANG: C.UTF-8
  - POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK: Off
  - XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: XFCE
  - XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP: lightdm-xsession
  - XAUTHORITY: /home/cd/.Xauthority
  - XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR: /var/lib/lightdm/data/cd
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh-P6aZyYicwGNX/agent.1219
  - SHELL: /usr/bin/zsh
  - GDMSESSION: lightdm-xsession
  - QT_ACCESSIBILITY: 1
  - XDG_VTNR: 7
  - PWD: /home/cd
  - XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share
  - XDG_CONFIG_DIRS: /etc/xdg
  - SESSION_MANAGER: local/n0tk4li:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1219,unix/n0tk4li:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1219
  - PANEL_GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS: 0
  - DISPLAY: :0.0
  - GDK_BACKEND: x11
  - NO_AT_BRIDGE: 1
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 38161
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 2a236bb5-e808-4a53-82e1-6b2293602f71
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
--------------------------------------------------------

Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.008 Sec
Failed to launch pgAdmin4. Error:
Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT
```

What was the first challenge? There was a broken link to python's system at /usr/pgadmin/venv/bin:

```
python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.9
```

This was corrected with:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python python3
```

But, even fixing the link, the GUI kept showing a message about not having "flask":

```
Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.005 Sec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py", line 49, in <module>
    import config

  File "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

After many attempts, the procedures I've done that allowed to run pgadmin4 were:

```
sudo chown -R cd:cd /usr/pgadmin4
cd /usr/pgadmin4
rm -fr venv
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v8.2/pip/pgadmin4-8.2-py3-none-any.whl
python -m pip install pgadmin4-8.2-py3-none-any.whl
```